# How to create new core on Apache Solr Certified by Bitnami?

Tags: solr, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I'm super duper new to Solr, it's my first time and just deployed `Apache Solr Certified by Bitnami` on Google Cloud Platform this morning. According to the documentation from Bitnami,

[Get Started with Solr by Bitnami](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFQXU.png)

but the following error msg pop out once I followed the instruction.

[cmd_err_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2efHG.png)

Meanwhile, the Solr dashboard shows the following error msg too

[Solr Dashboard err_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owCYK.png)

I'm not sure whether should I add `solrconfig.xml` manually or not, may anyone help, please?

Sorry if this is a very stupid question, hopefully may find out the solution here, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 hours of trial&error, I found a solution myself.

For those who might have the same problem, the solution is copy the `solrconfig.xml` from the following path

`/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf`

and paste it into the directory of your new core

`/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/NEW_CORE/conf`

Comment: Bitnami can be very frustrating with their outdated documentation.  I had to change my path from "apache-solr" to just "solr" in case anyone else encounters this.  
$  cd /opt/bitnami/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf